Why doesn't Typescript understand the concept of variables?
If I do this:
const prompts = [
    {
      prompt: task,
      role: 'user'
    }
  ]

  const threadId = await createThread(prompts)

Typescript complains, saying this:

Argument of type '{ prompt: string; role: string; }[]' is not
assignable to parameter of type '{ prompt: string; metadata?: object |
undefined; role: "user" | "assistant"; }[]'.   Type '{ prompt: string;
role: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ prompt: string;
metadata?: object | undefined; role: "user" | "assistant"; }'.
Types of property 'role' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"user" | "assistant"'.ts(2345) const prompts: {
prompt: string;
role: string; }[]

However, if I put it directly into the function call like this:
const threadId = await createThread([{prompt: task, role: 'user'}])

Typescript is like "Oh, OK. Yeah that works. What are variables anyway?"
Isn't this, I don't know, overly stupid? Frequently I have to REDECLARE types in both the caller and in the function itself. It's the number one thing I find annoying with Typescript. I can never refactor code because then Typescript complains.

So why not just use a const assertion: const prompts = [...] as const;? Or, if you have a type defined, just use that type: const prompts: Prompt[] = [...];

Type inference is fairly linear. In general, TypeScript does not infer the type of a variable based on how it is used but rather based on its initial value. The type of prompts is not impacted by the parameter types of the createThread function.

"Frequently I have to REDECLARE types in both the caller and in the function itself." If you're declaring the same type multiple times, then you're just using the language wrong.

@RobbyCornelissen Wow, Robby. Almost as if I should, I don't know, ask questions about it on a webpage based on asking questions and receiving answers!

This is a case for using the satisfies operator: see this question. You can use const prompts = […] satisfies Parameters<typeof createThread>[0] to constrain the value and TS will accept it at the usage site (example).

@jsejcksn Wow, now that's what I call a simple, elegant, and above all intuitive solution.

Yeah I gotta say TS is less than intuitive in many ways and its error messages—oh my. It’s a nice idea but needs a LOT of help in the usability department. Most typed languages make types easy and almost invisible—very low friction. Not TS. Not at all. By far the hardest type system I’ve used with the lowest return on investment. I’ve never had it catch an error for me but I have actually had it mask one, and I’ve had it clutter my code and waste a ton my time fiddling with type declarations and reading horrible type error messages that were wrong. Rant over. :)

@RobbyCornelissen I haven't seen anyone explain what to do or why it behaves the way it does.
Just now I had to redeclare a type TWO times. First in a state setter, then in the function call, and in the function itself. I'm so goddamn tired of Typescript's stupidity.

I too am quite tired of TS. It’s the fad of the month and so everyone uses it, and so everyone HAS to use it no matter how much worse it makes everything. And to be honest I think some people just LIKE it, full stop. And I can in a weird way understand that bc after being forced to use it and then working on JS code, it feels unnerving like I’m flying blind. Even though I know I’ve never once had TS catch an error for me and that it has caused a lot of problems. I do think JS needs types. I just don’t think TS is the answer. Or maybe JS can’t have a good type system for some reason. Dunno.

That said there may be well be good reasons for TS to exist and even be the main JS solution. But in that case I wish it wasn’t so painful to use. As I said I’m a firm believer that a type system should do its job and get out of the way. It should serve the user not the other way around.

So... don't use it. What's the point of ranting about it here? As far as the question is concerned, you could have just declared a type Prompt = { /* whatever you need it to be */ } and use it in your state setter and your function call, but hey, don't let solutions stand in the way of your manufactured outrage.

Where am I saying you have to declare it twice? I just said declare it once and use the same type throughout. Also, as for the "fanboy" comment: every language has its strengths and weaknesses. If you feel that those weaknesses outweigh its strengths, then... just don't use it.

@RobbyCornelissen "you could have just declared a type Prompt = { /* whatever you need it to be */ } and use it in your state setter and your function call"
Notice the word "and".

@RobbyCornelissen Didn't know I wasn't allowed to ask questions about Typescript. My bad, I guess. I will make sure to only say positive things about Typescript in the future to satisfy the fanboys.

You are aware that "declaring" a type and "using" a type are two different things, right?

@Yeats When you realize that "user" is a subtype of string (a specific string), it will make more sense. I think what can be confusing is the behavior of const assertions which are a convenient shorthand. "user" as const is a shorthand for "user" as "user"

@RobbyCornelissen No.

@AluanHaddad I understand that. Tell it to Typescript. That's the one who doesn't understand.

@AluanHaddad Do you seriously not see that something is a bit off when you have to write the phrase: "user" as "user"?

@Yeats the only way to do that would be to restrict the type of the variable based on all known usages. This would be complicated and likely even less intuitive.

@Yeats I think you aren't considering what I'm getting at. I agree that it's counterintuitive and confusing. I'm just explaining why it behaves the way it does. It's the lesser evil.

The reason is that somebody might do:
const prompts = [
    {
      prompt: task,
      role: 'user'
    }
  ]

prompts[0].role = 'hehe';

const threadId = await createThread(prompts) // uh oh, hehe is not a valid role!

That is, variables are variable. Their contents might change.
Now, in theory, TypeScript could look at this code and reason that the reassignment is invalid because we later call createThread, which requires role to be 'user' or 'assistant'. However, that would mean the compilation error depends on code that follows, or more generally, code that might be elsewhere. After all, prompts might be exported, imported in another file, and used there in a way that is not compatible. Even worse, that incompatible use might be written, and compiled, after the assignment was compiled, possibly even in a separate npm package.
As you can see, restricting the use of a variable depending on how others use it opens up quite the can of worms. That's why TypeScript infers the type of a variable not from all uses, but only from the initial value.
And usually, when people create a variable with the initial value of 'user', they mean to be able to put arbitrary strings in there, not just the initial string they provided. And that's why typescript assumes that the roles in prompt are strings.
To fix this, you can either tell typescript that role never changes, thereby prodding it to infer a type of 'user' rather than string:
const prompts = [
    {
      prompt: task,
      role: 'user' as const;
    }
  ]

Or you can specify the type of the variable exlicitly:
const prompts: Prompt[] = [
    {
      prompt: task,
      role: 'user'
    }
  ]

where Prompt is some suitably defined type, for instance:
interface Prompt { 
    prompt: string; 
    metadata?: object; 
    role: "user" | "assistant"; 
}


Frequently I have to REDECLARE types in both the caller and in the function itself

That doesn't follow. You can declare the type once and use it for declaring both createThread and prompts:
const prompts: Prompt[] = { ... }
function createThread(prompts: Prompt[]) { ...}

I'd recommend the shared type definition, because it gives you code completion while writing the object literal, showing errors right away rather than when the incorrectly initialized object is used.

Someone might do prompts[0].prompt = false as well.

False. Not without triggering a "Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'." error.

Sure, but they'd get a compilation error, because the initial value for prompt is of type string, and TypeScript knows that false is not a string. If you don't specify the type, TypeScript will guess it from the initial value. In the case of prompt, that guess is string, which fits the expectations of createThread. In the case of role, it's also string, but createThread has narrower expectations than that.

@meriton Hahahahahahaha

@Yeats there's no need for that. You're shooting the messenger because you don't like care for how the language infers types in certain situations.

To sum up your chain of logic: I have to redeclare role because someone might change the role later to something that is the wrong type and Typescript can't read code. What's that you say? Someone might change prompt as well? No, because Typescript can read code and see that false is not a string. Duh. Any idiot can see that.

What's more likely: That somebody puts first a string and then a boolean into the same variable, or that somebody puts first a string, and then a different string, into the same variable? The first is very unusual, and likely not intended. The second is very common. Would you prefer the language to treat both alike? Put differently, if you do unusual things (such as a string that may only be 'user' or 'assistant'), TypeScript requires you to be more explicit, because it assumes the common, rather than the uncommon, case by default.

@meriton So Typescript does a risk analysis and says "Well, he can easily create a mistake here so I'm going to warn him, even though I can warn him AFTER he makes the mistake. If he's dumb enough to put a boolean instead of a string, though, I'm not going to warn him neither before nor after. Screw him." Yes OF COURSE I would prefer the language to not behave arbitrarily lol

When you attach a value to an identifier then typescript try to infer it from the type of the value. If you have provided "user" then it will treat as a string not literal user

This is known as a const assertion. A const assertion tells the
compiler to infer the narrowest* or most specific type it can for an
expression. If you leave it off, the compiler will use its default
type inference behavior, which will possibly result in a wider or more
general type. - jcalz

You can read more here What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case?

You can do const assertion so that ts will see it as a literal not as a string.
const prompts = [
    {
        prompt: task,
        role: 'user' as const
    }
  ];



Yes, but it would be helpful to explain why.

But prompt is ok? I swear Typescript is using a random generator to produce its errors.

@Yeats it's not random. If you go to the definition of createThread you will see that role and prompt have different types.

@AluanHaddad Of course they have different types. So Typescript throws a fit only when it comes to certain types. That's what I mean. Random.

@Yeats no. You need to take a step back. I agree that it isn't obvious and that the solutions are even less obvious, however there's nothing arbitrary about this behavior. It is a tradeoff.

Nothing arbitrary about wanting me to more specific about one type and not another? What could be more abitrary than that? Would it complain about a number but not a boolean? How am I supposed to know?
I also notice no one has even begun to answer my base question.

Think about it from the POV of the function you are calling. There are discreet set of strings that are valid roles but any string is a valid prompt. How to describe this so you can't call it wrong?

What is your base question. If you feel it has not been answered. Please highlight it and change the language/tone of the question a bit. Might help

@TusharShahi There is a thing called "question marks". They look like this, ?, and indicate a question. I didn't know I had to highlight a question more than that.

@AluanHaddad I have now thought about it from the POV of the function I am calling. It should have no problem understanding it, like it does without the middleman of a variable.

@Yeats but what if you were to write prompts[0].role = "asdf"; between the line where you create the array of prompts and the line where you pass it in to the function?

@AluanHaddad But I didn't. And what if I wrote prompts[0].prompt = null?

@Yeats that's an error because null isn't a subtype of string. What is confusing about const assertions is that they infer the type is if the variable were immutable but they they don't make it immutable.

@AluanHaddad And how does Typescript know that null is not a string? LOL

@Yeats It is a presupposition.

@AluanHaddad It almost sounds like.... Typescript CAN read code. It just arbitrarily chooses to throw errors for some things.

@Yeats reapproach the issue from the question "why am I using TypeScript?". The language doesn't allow you to write anything that you can't write in JavaScript. It's purpose is to help detect errors and use apis correctly. If you are using the language for another purpose, you probably won't see the purpose of it.

@AluanHaddad Actually Typescript seems to never catch actual mistakes, it only forces overly redundant declaring of variables but then lets actual errors slip through no problem.

@Yeats my experience has been otherwise. Again, you don't need to use TypeScript if you don't want to. Some people never learned TS independently but rather from frameworks like Angular which do their best of require it (although they can't). TS is optional and that is one of its major and stated aspects/features.

@AluanHaddad Just wish I could use it for some things rather than all things. If I could use it to watch over what gets returned in an API or something, that'd be useful. But no. If you use it you have to massacre your code with Typescript declarations.

@Yeats that's incorrect. You can use it on a file by file basis. You can mix TS and JS source files very easily.

@AluanHaddad Nah
